# Why does IE glitches heavily on this layout?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, position, fixed

This demo where a `position:fixed` modal appears when you click the button: http://liveweave.com/Du9sLR Works in Chrome / Firefox but in IE, it doesn't

As big as the parent container.

[image: As big as the container]

When you select text it does this weird thing.

[image: when you select text]

Somehow when you add `position` / `overflow` and `border-radius` on the parent container it doens't work. In IE the modal gets as big as the parent container.

Or does it? Because when you select the text and go down with the mouse a new red box appears below it with some of the text. And a scrollbar appears if you recreate this demo in an empty page.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Well, the page is displayed in quirks mode, so it's probably a quirk. Does the issue persist in standards mode?

Comment: Yes. it works in IE8 / IE7 though. Probably because they don't have `border-radius`